# Problema con el servlet de una aplicación web desarrollada en java

Tags: java, jsp, eclipse, servlets, web

Estoy desarrollando un aplicación web en java, y al enviar objetos o variables de cualquier tipo al jsp este me las envía null. Estoy utilizando eclipse y en el archivo en el archivo web.xml ya e creado tambien lo necesario

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DesafioActividadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.DesafioActividadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DesafioActividadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DesafioActividadServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

```html
 <form action="DesafioActividadServlet" method="GET">
    <%if (request.getAttribute("desafio")!=null){ %>
        <%!Desafio des = new Desafio();%>
        <%des=(Desafio)  request.getAttribute("desafio"); %>
        <%!String descripcion = des.getDescripcion();%>
        <%=descripcion%>
    <%}else{%>
        <h1>Me trajo null</h1>
    <%} %>
</form>
```

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Desafio des= new Desafio();
    des= DesafioLleno(); 

    //Este comentario es de la prueba al enviar una variable string llamada cadena
    //String cadena="Hola";
    //request.setAttribute("desafio", cadena);
    //getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/pages/desafio-actividad.jsp").forward(request,response);

    request.setAttribute("desafio", des );
    RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/desafio-actividad.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);


}

protected Desafio DesafioLleno(){
    Desafio des= new Desafio();
    des.setCodigo("111111");
    des.setDescripcion("Que entre en el servlet");
    des.setEstatus('A');
    des.setOrg("Marna");

    return des;
}
```

Comment: Luis, puedes imprimir el valor de `des`???

Comment: @sioesi Si el código que muestra es correcto, nunca puede ser `null`.

Comment: @SJuan76 es que me llama la atencion la manera de como quiere mostrar los datos en el servlet

Comment: @sioesi A mí también, pero necesito escribir una respuesta para explicárselo. De todas formas, `desafio` no debería ser `null` a pesar de esos posibles fallos.

Comment: Pregunta, cuando dices "me sale null", significa que en el navegador sale "<h1>Me trajo null</h1>" o simplemente, "null" a secas. En el último caso, mi comentario de más abajo es la respuesta correcta (el atributo `descripción` no se actualiza al ejecutar el método `service`). Si no, comprueba que el servlet se ejecute de verdad, y que las etiquetas del atributo coincidan (por si hay alguna chorrada de acentos, espacios en blanco, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Según a lo que te refieras por "me sale null", igual lo de más abajo no está  directamente relacionado con el `null`, pero veo una serie de errores en tu código y necesito el espacio para comentarlos:

1. Estás mezclando `<%` y `<%!`. El código, tal como lo marcas, te generaría un Servlet tal que:

   ```
   public class NombreServletJsp extends HttpServlet {
     ...
     Desafio des = new Desafio();
     String descripcion = des.getDescripcion();
     ...
     public void service (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       ... 
       des=(Desafio)  request.getAttribute("desafio"); 
       response.out.println(descripcion)
       ...
      }
   ...
   }
   ```

   En otras palabras, lo que va dentro de `<%` va dentro del método service y lo que va dentro de `<%!` va fuera. Por ejemplo, con tu código no te actualizaría el valor de `descripcion` y tu JSP siempre mostraría el valor por defecto de `descripcion`.
2. Además, no necesitas abrir un tag en cada línea. Esto

   ```
   <%if (request.getAttribute("desafio")!=null) { 
      Desafio des = new Desafio();
      des=(Desafio)  request.getAttribute("desafio");
      String descripcion = des.getDescripcion();%>
      <%=descripcion%>
   <%}else{%>
   ```

   o, incluso mejor esto,

   ```
   <%if (request.getAttribute("desafio")!=null) { 
      Desafio des = (Desafio) request.getAttribute("desafio");
      String descripcion = des.getDescripcion();
      response.out.println(descripcion);
   }else{%>
   ```

   es completamente legal y mucho más fácil de leer. Y por supuesto, esto

   ```
   <%
      Desafio des = (Desafio) request.getAttribute("desafio");
      if (des!=null) { 
        response.out.println(
            des.getDescripcion());
      }else{%>
   ```

   es incluso mejor.
3. Y, por supuesto, al definir una variable no tienes porqué instanciar un objeto si immediatamente después vas a sobreescribirlo; en vez de

   ```
   Desafio des = new Desafio();
   des = DesafioLleno()
   ```

   haz

   ```
   Desafio des = DesafioLleno();
   ```

   ; esto no es que te vaya a provocar un error si no lo corriges, pero irá un poquísimo más lento y, sobretodo, queda muy feo.

Comment: Ah sí, los scriptlets (meter código java en tags `<%`) se consideran obsoletos; si estás modificando código antiguo no continúa usándolos, pero para proyectos nuevos considera empezar a usar al menos JSTL y EL.

Comment: Recomendaría que este comentario forme parte directa de la respuesta, como un consejo adicional (tal como he visto que hacemos en el sitio en inglés)